# ffplay - capture image snapshot

Tags: video

How can I capture image snapshot from playing video using `ffplay` player?

I have searched in ffplay documentation and didn't find any related commands.

Thanks

Comment: @slhck I want interactive image capture from ffplay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ffplay` cannot do that. It will only allow you to pause and seek in the file via keyboard shortcuts.

If you want to interactively create screenshots from a video playback, you should have a look at:

1. **VLC**: Go to *Video → Snapshot* or press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift-S</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd-Alt-S</kbd> on macOS). See here for [more info](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Snapshots/).
2. **mpv**: Press the <kbd>S</kbd> key. See [here](https://defkey.com/mpv-media-player-shortcuts) for a list of shortcuts.

An alternative would be to just use `ffmpeg`, but that is non-interactive:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:45 -i input.mp4 -frames:v 1 image.png
```

Comment: perfect. Thank you for the answer. And I found mpv is more interesting.

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, mpv is much more capable in terms of playback.